# Custom PC input peripheral

Tags: input, controller

I would like to somehow plug an extra button to my computer that when pressed would execute some shell script.

Backstory: I'm a programmer and I very much wish I had a big red button to commence the deployment of whatever it is I'm working on. This button when pressed would trigger the execution of some script on my computer and do nothing until released and pressed again. Also I would prefer if it connected through USB. I imagine this one button will be simple to hook up and be enough for a while, but I'd also like a solution that would work for multiple (4-16) buttons for example (on a nice wooden control panel).

When answering, please keep in mind that I don't know much about electronics.

Comment: (1) The question is too broad.  (2)  Look up *USB big red button* on google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157710/how-can-i-reprogram-a-usb-easy-button

Comment: Paint a button on your keyboard red...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider hacking an USB keyboard.

Basically take a keyboard, open it up, and wire your control panel to, say, function keys?

For "bonus" points, you can try wiring up 'non-existent keys' (keys that would exist on a matrix keyboard but have not been populated in the most popular layouts (F13-F24's come to mind, most PC keyboards leave it at F1-F12). They probably still exist as keys on the interconnect matrix, just the key array itself is not wired for them. (Lookup Matrix Keyboard for details, or indicate in comments if you're interested in additional explanation).

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to implement this will be by using a microcontroller that can present itself as a USB HID keyboard. One readily available microcontroller that has this capability is the Atmel Atmega32U4, which is present in the Arduino Micro (and the common Pro Micro variant).

Sample code and schematics for precisely this application (having a button that enters text when pushed) is available on the Arduino web site at:

http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/KeyboardMessage

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the hacked keyboard (easiest) or microcontroller with native usb, there is two other options. Emulated usb on smaller microcontrollers can do this. V-usb and similar for attiny or msp430s or pics. All three versions rely on the USB HID keyboard standard, which means generic no driver needed for usb computers since like 2000. The computer side requires a hotkey program to work I THINK newer versions of windows have hotkey options to start programs, and OSX definately does, through the shortcut control panel and the automator scripting program.

The last option, simplier than the usb micros but slightly more difficult than a hacked keyboard is a microcontroller to usb-serial adaptor. Simpler to program, but might require drivers, and requires a hotkey program or script to monitor a serial port on the computer.

Other versions can include usb microcontrollers as a USB HID gamepad or joystick, or as a usb-serial device (without an external adaptor).